# RunTime Error '2147467259 (80004005)' Sending Email from VBA Code

Tags: vba, email, ms-access, outlook

I am trying to send an email of a file from my VB code. I have a linked table that has email addresses in it, but I am getting the run time error **'-2147467259 (80004005)' We Need to Know Who to Send this to. Make sure you enter atleast one name'**

```
Public Function sendmail(mailSub As String, mailTo As String, _
       Optional msgBody As String, Optional mailCC As String, _
       Optional mailBCC As String, Optional mailFrom As String, _
                                Optional pathToAttach As String) As Boolean

Dim oApp As Object, oMail As Object, oAttach As Object
sendmail = False

Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(0) 'olMailItem=0
Set oAttach = oMail.Attachments
With oMail
    .BodyFormat = 2 'olFormatHTML=2, olFormatPlain=1, olFormatRichText=3
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = mailFrom
    .To = mailTo
    .CC = mailCC
    .BCC = mailBCC
    .Subject = mailSub
    .htmlBody = msgBody & "<BR>" & .htmlBody
    .Recipients.ResolveAll
End With
If pathToAttach & "" <> "" Then oAttach.Add pathToAttach,  olByValue, 1
oMail.Send   '<<This is where I am getting the error
oMail.Display

sendmail = True
Exit Function


End Function

Public Function getEmails(Address_type As String) As String
    Dim rst As Recordset, tbl_Email As String
    tbl_Email = "tbl_Email" ' Change this as needed
    On Error GoTo no_rec
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM " & tbl_Email & " WHERE " & _
                                   Address_type & "=TRUE")
    rst.MoveLast
    rst.MoveFirst

    While Not rst.EOF
        getEmails = getEmails & rst![Email] & ";"
        rst.MoveNext
    Wend
no_rec:
    If Not rst Is Nothing Then rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: what is the value inside `mailTo`?

Comment: mailTo is set as a string. In my LinkedTable, I have one email address set as "To". It is to 'IndyManagers,' so a string.  The way the table is set up, it has a FriendlyName column, then an email address column. I have used this format before and never had an issue so I am not sure why I am now

Comment: It's not clear how the two methods you posted are related?

Comment: I was showing where I was retrieving the emails, which was from my LinkedTable

Comment: But we're missing the linking code, where you call `getEmails` and then pass the returned data to `sendmail`

Comment: sendmail "CPO_AFC: " & CStr(SD) & " to " & CStr(ED), getEmails("To"), , getEmails("CC"), getEmails("BCC"), "wfreporting@lowes.com", makeXl

Comment: My code is very long, I was just trying to include pieces that were relevant. The one above is my sendMail code

Comment: In `sendmail` add a line `Debug.Print "To", mailTo ` - what output do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is no reason to call **both** Send **and** Display: if you are displaying the message, you should not call Send - the user will click the Send button.

If you replace the call to Send with Save, do you see the recipients in the message shown to the user?

Comment: As Dmitry mentioned，If you are displaying the message, you should not call Send.I tested your code. If you comment oMail.Send or oMail.Display. The code works fine.